# Java - Any way to make variable unmodifiable after being set in the constructor?

Tags: java, final

I have a member variable that in a class that I want to make sure nothing changes it after it is set in the constructor. So, it would look something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private String myVar = null;

    public MyClass(DataObj dataObj)
    {
        myVar = dataObj.getFinalVarValue();
        //at this point I don't want anything to be able change the value of myVar
    }

    ....
}
```

My first thought was to see I could just add the `final` modifier to the variable, but the compiler complains about assigning a value to the final field. Is it possible to accomplish this?

Comment: CLone and make setters private?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler complains (in the constructor), because you already provide an initialization by writing

```
private String myVar = null;
```

remove the '`= null`' part. Add `final` and assign the value in the constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private final String myVar;

    public MyClass(DataObj dataObj)
    {
        myVar = dataObj.getFinalVarValue(); // the only assignment/init happens here.
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: I've always been an advocate of always setting an initial value to variables when they are declared, but this makes perfect sense. Thanks. I'll accept once the 5 minutes is up.

Answer (score 1):

Make it `private`, and then don't include a setter. As long as you never change it in within the class methods, it's immutable.

Comment: It does not answer the original question; the answer by MartinK does.

Comment: @alf Technically, it does. I wasn't aware of Java allowing you to set the final once in the constructor, but this is an effective means of keeping a variable immutable by outside sources without making it final. I'll leave it, but I do acknowledge that MartinK's answer is better.

Answer (score -1):

String objects are already immutable. So adding the **private final** modificator is enough.

Comment: Still does not answer the original question. Did you care to read it?

Comment: Also in this case you should split the declaration and initialization.

Comment: @alf he asked about not changing the value of the var, not the Object it's pointing to.